# Using Multiple Types In Google Places

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I need to set multiple types in the URL

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?sensor=true&key=API_KEY&location=LAT,LNG&rankby=distance&types=[]

without using the parameter key "keyword"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately according to Google's places API this is not yet supported and there is no consistent work around. The only way to truly achieve multiple types is to have multiple API calls.

From the google API on supported types.

> ... Only one type may be specified (if more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored)